# unwanted tar,zip,jar disributions in gradle build

Tags: gradle, jar, zip, war, tar

I am doing gradle build, which includes a number of projects. When i run 
`gradle build`
 command its generating unwanted bundles like tar,zip. So what should i do to exclude these tasks

[image]

am using war plugin to generate war ( `apply plugin: 'war'` ).
am also using following plugins

```
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'org.asciidoctor.gradle.asciidoctor'
apply plugin: 'war'
```

am also using plugin `asciidoctor`

**UPDATE**

I have used

```
distTar.enabled = false
distZip.enabled = false
```

To solve this, but When i try to upload with

```
gradle upload
```

Its giving the following error

```
> Could not publish configuration 'archives'
```

Comment: I got another solution from following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33774782/upload-only-war-jar-files-in-gradlerestrict-zip-tar-generation-and-upload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running the `build` task, which is defined in the `java` plugin of Gradle and is one of the lifecycle tasks. According to [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#N120B8), `build` task depends on `check` and `assemble` tasks and performs a full build of the project.

Since `check` task performs all verification tasks in the project and `assemble` assembles all the archives in the project, you've got this behaviour, when all the task are executed.

If you want to provide some specific task execution order, which will include only subset of all tasks, you can simply do not use the `build` task, but provide your own custom task or just call some exactly task (for example `war`), which will do, what you want. Furthermore, you are free to specify the execution order with `dependsOn` and `mustRunAfter` properties of the tasks if it's needed.

Comment: I have did distTar.enabled = false,distZip.enabled = false to solve this. but now i have issue in gradle upload(uploadArchives). getting the error "Could not publish configuration 'archives'"

Comment: @arjuncc disabling tasks will never let you run them, so in some situations it's not a good solution. As for the new exception, it's better to post new question for it and provide your build script content, because it's probably has nothing common with the question above.