# Upload only war/jar files in gradle(restrict zip/tar generation and upload)

Tags: gradle, upload

My build script is like as follows. I use `gradle build` command to build and `gradle upload` command to upload the artifact. My problem is a tar,zip file is also generated with this command and get uploaded. I dont want it. Only things I would like to get uploaded is 'jar' and 'war' files.
I have also a related question posted by me yesterday [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755385/unwanted-tar-zip-jar-disributions-in-gradle-build).

**More details(I have excluded some unwanted code)**

**build file in root**

```
allprojects  {
  apply plugin: 'maven'
 group = 'groupid'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}

subprojects {
  apply plugin: 'java'
  sourceCompatibility = 1.7
  targetCompatibility = 1.7


    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username "$nexusUser"
                password "$nexusPass"
            }
            url "$nexusUrl"
        }
    }

    uploadArchives {
        repositories {
            mavenDeployer {
                repository(url: "$nexusSnapshotUrl") {
                    authentication(userName: "$nexusUser", password: "$nexusPass")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

ext.comlib = [ // Groovy map literal
                  junit3: "junit:junit:3.8",
                  junit4: "junit:junit:4.9",
                  spring_core: "org.springframework:spring-core:3.1",
                  hibernate_validator : "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.1.3.Final",
                  spring_core : "org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:4.0.2.RELEASE",
                  spring_security_web: "org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.0.2.RELEASE",
                  spring_security_config: "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:4.0.2.RELEASE",
                  spring_boot_starter_test: "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:1.2.5.RELEASE",
                  spring_boot_starter_actuator: "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:1.2.5.RELEASE",
                  spring_boot_plugin_gradle: "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.6.RELEASE",
                  asciidoctor_gradle_plugin: "org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-gradle-plugin:1.5.1",
                  asciidoctor_pdf_plugin: "org.asciidoctor:asciidoctorj-pdf:1.5.0-alpha.9"/*,
                  sl4j_api: "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12",
                  sl4j_log4j: "org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.12",
                  logback_classic: "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3",
                  logback_core: "ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.3"*/
]
```

**build file in sub module**

```
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
group = 'com.group.id'
apply from: "../build.gradle"
apply plugin: 'org.asciidoctor.gradle.asciidoctor'

apply plugin: 'war'

description = 'module name'
dependencies {
    compile "someothermodule:commonapi:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
    compile "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.0.1"
    compile project(':dependingproject1:dependingproject2')
    compile comlib.spring_boot_starter_actuator
    compile comlib.spring_core
    compile comlib.spring_security_web
    compile comlib.spring_security_config
    testCompile(comlib.spring_boot_starter_test) {
exclude(module: 'commons-logging')
    }
    testCompile comlib.junit4
    providedCompile comlib_app.spring_boot_plugin_tomcat
    testCompile "io.springfox:springfox-staticdocs:2.0.3"
    testCompile "org.springframework:spring-test:4.1.7.RELEASE"
}

ext {
    swaggerOutputDir = file("src/docs/asciidoc/generated")
    asciiDocOutputDir = file("${buildDir}/asciidoc")
}

test {
    systemProperty 'org.springframework.restdocs.outputDir', asciiDocOutputDir
    systemProperty 'io.springfox.staticdocs.outputDir', swaggerOutputDir

}

//spring boot plugin
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username "$nexusUser"
                password "$nexusPass"
            }
            url "$nexusCentral"
        }
        maven {
            credentials {
                username "$nexusUser"
                password "$nexusPass"
            }
            url "$nexusThirdParty"

        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath(comlib.spring_boot_plugin_gradle)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Included the following code snippet in my gradle file

```
[distZip, distTar].each { task -> configurations.archives.artifacts.removeAll
{ it.class.simpleName == "ArchivePublishArtifact" && it.archiveTask == task }

task.enabled = false
}
```

For more details refer [this link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2679). Its issue with spring boot plugin.

Comment: 1.5 years later and still distTar adds to uploadArchives even when the task is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

arjuncc's solution doesn't seem to work on Gradle 4.10.2, so here's one that works and uses public APIs, hopefully it will continue to work.

```
configurations.archives.artifacts.removeAll {
    // exclude from the archives configuration all artifacts that were generated by distZip & distTar
    def depTasks = it.getBuildDependencies().getDependencies()
    depTasks.contains(distZip) || depTasks.contains(distTar)  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More or less the same as ajuncc's solution, but perhaps a bit more simple. Remove all .tar artifacts from the archives configuration:

```
configurations.archives.artifacts.removeAll {PublishArtifact publishArtifact -> publishArtifact.type == 'tar'}
```