# Publish only JAR to maven repo

Tags: java, gradle, maven-plugin

I want to upload a generated jar file to packagecloud.io.

My shortened `build.gradle`:

```
jar {
  archiveName "$project.name-$project.version-SNAPSHOT.jar"
}

distTar {
  archiveName 'dist.tar'
}

//project.configurations.archives.artifacts.clear()
artifacts {
  archives( file( "$buildDir/libs/$project.name-$project.version-SNAPSHOT.jar" ) )
}

uploadArchives {
  repositories.mavenDeployer {
    pom.version = project.version + '-SNAPSHOT'
    configuration = configurations.deployerJars
    repository( url:'packagecloud+https://packagecloud.io/mycompany/central' ){
        authentication password:pw
    }
  }
}

jar.finalizedBy uploadArchives
```

when I run `gradlew distTar`, the jar file is generated along with tar, and is uploaded to the repo, but the build fails with exceptions:

```
> Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :jar
> Task :startScripts
> Task :distTar

> Task :uploadArchives
Could not transfer artifact io.mozaiq:feature-state-verticle:pom:0.1-20190509.110559-1 from/to remote (packagecloud+https://packagecloud.io/mozaiq/central): Upload failed: {"error":"Validation failed: Unknown Java::Version::UnsupportedPackaging"}
Could not transfer artifact io.mozaiq:feature-state-verticle:tar:0.1-20190509.110559-1 from/to remote (packagecloud+https://packagecloud.io/mozaiq/central): Upload failed: {"error":"Could not understand this request, please contact support@packagecloud.io"}

> Task :uploadArchives FAILED
```

so, for some reason it tries to upload not only the jar file, but all the artefacts generated.

How can I restrict publishing to a jar file only?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload only war/jar files in gradle(restrict zip/tar generation and upload)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33774782/upload-only-war-jar-files-in-gradlerestrict-zip-tar-generation-and-upload)

Comment: @M.Ricciuti in the "solution" the dist* tasks are simply disabled, which is totally wrong! I need to have both tasks executed `uploadArchives` AND `distTar`

Comment: I think the other solutions given in this question are best approaches: try to remove *.zip/*.tar from the "archives" configuration. there is also this related question on the Gradle forum : https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-exclude-zip-only-from-archives-for-maven-repo-upload/13354

Comment: tried that as well in different combinations, see upd

Comment: @M.Ricciuti after playing with your link (which didn't work), I managed to get it up and running with no probs. I ended up adding `configurations.archives.artifacts.removeAll{ 'jar' != it.type }`. Feel free to answer the question, so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on answers from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33774782/upload-only-war-jar-files-in-gradlerestrict-zip-tar-generation-and-upload) and [this post](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-exclude-zip-only-from-archives-for-maven-repo-upload/13354) from Gradle forum: a solution would be to exclude all artifacts which are not 'jar' from the `archives` configuration. This way, the `uploadArchives` will only upload Jar artifacts, skipped all other produced artifacts/

```
configurations.archives.artifacts.removeAll{
    it.extension != 'jar'
}
```

This is similar to your own solution which is based on artifact 'type' .